# Variable not defined in loop?

Tags: c++, variables, for-loop, scope

It's saying on line 13: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Fib[40];
    Fib[0] = 1;
    Fib[1] = 1;
    cout << Fib[0] << Fib[1] << endl;

    for (int i=2; i<40; i++)
    Fib[i]=Fib[i-1]+Fib[i-2];
        cout << Fib[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: For loops only last for one line if there are no braces.

Comment: You're aware that because you didn't use curly braces only the first statement is inside the loop yes? the `cout << Fib[i] << endl;` line is outside the for loop. Also fix your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to scope the instructions you want to be executed in the loop:

```
for (int i=2; i<40; i++) {
    Fib[i]=Fib[i-1]+Fib[i-2];
    cout << Fib[i] << endl;
}
```

Loops will only execute a single instruction or a single scope of instructions. In your code, only the first line was part of the loop. The second was not, and therefore `i` was out of scope. Whether you indent the lines or not doesn't matter at all in C++. The compiler doesn't care about indentation; it is used only to aid the programmer, not the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The last line has [i] it is not inside the loop 
cout << Fib[i] << endl;
the scope of i is only within the for loop as i is declared within the loop according to new ISO standard so the correct line would be

```
for (int i=2; i<40; i++) {
    Fib[i]=Fib[i-1]+Fib[i-2];
    cout << Fib[i] << endl;
}
```